# SVG image not display android

Tags: svg-android

I use library `svg-android.jar` from https://code.google.com/p/svg-android. Image not display.

I tried `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` but doesn't work.

I dont know how fixed this.

Comment: What is the error you have? Show us your code, the expected result and the current result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to the imageview
What android version are you using?